# Getting tuples from each child tables in H2

Tags: sql, database, h2

I have a table (PERSON) in h2 database:

```
id primary
name
age
address
company
```

And three other tables with `id` as foreign key in them (COMP1, COMP2, COMP3):

```
id foreign references PERSON(id)
department
```

Suppose I want to fetch a total of 18 names from PERSON tables, and condition is that there should be 6 people from each of the COMPx tables chosen randomly. My attempt:

```
SELECT name AS "Candidate's name" 
FROM PERSON 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM COMP1 WHERE department='sales' 
  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 6 
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM COMP2 WHERE department='production' 
  ORDER BY RANDOM LIMIT 6 
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM COMP3 WHERE department='supply'
  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 6
);
```

Throws this error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Scalar subquery contains more than one row.

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of SQL syntax, you are close. You need to enclose each subquery that is UNION-ed in parenthesis. For example:

```
SELECT name AS "Candidate's name" 
FROM PERSON 
WHERE id IN (
  (SELECT id FROM COMP1 WHERE department='sales' 
  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 6)
  UNION
  (SELECT id FROM COMP2 WHERE department='production' 
  ORDER BY RANDOM LIMIT 6 )
  UNION
  (SELECT id FROM COMP3 WHERE department='supply'
  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 6)
);
```

Comment: This query is returning rows all right, but their quantity is varying every time; sometimes the number of rows is 3, sometimes 8, sometimes 2. On manual inspection, I can see 40+ people eligible for this query. What seems to the problem?

Comment: Please provide some sample data to demostrate the specific case with issues.